# Node.js script running automatically on the first and last of the month

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server, cron

What I am trying to create is a script in node.js that will be added in a server of a web page that we are building. I want the script to do the following: In the first of every month to count the users inside my database and then create a set of tokens based on the amount of users logged in that current date. Specifically: 0,8 * numberOfUsers * 100. Then in the last day of every month count the users again and refund the tokens that were generated in the first of the month back to all the users (old and new). I also want to try that this runs automatically every time the server goes live and not have to execute it every time.

I am using the cron.schedule method and to check if it works I run for every minute the block that counts the first users(the one that is supposed to be in the first of the month) and every two minutes the block that gets again the new number of users and refunds the Tokens (the one that is supposed to be in the last of the month) . Here is my code:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const cron = require('node-cron');



// Connection configuration
const config = {
  user: '',
  password: '',
  host: '',
  database: ''
};


// Create a new connection pool
const pool = new Pool(config);

async function countUsers() {
    // Get number of users
    const query = `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users`;
    const res = await pool.query(query);
    const numUsers = +res.rows[0].count;
    console.log(numUsers);
    return numUsers;
  }
  


async function refundTokens(tokensToRefund,numUsers) {
    console.log("I am here");
    console.log(numUsers);
    if (numUsers !== 0 && !isNaN(tokensToRefund)) {
      // Calculate amount of tokens to give to each user
     const tokensPerUser = Math.round(tokensToRefund / numUsers);
    
      // Update tokens for all users
      const query = `UPDATE users SET tokens = tokens + $1`;
      await pool.query(query, [tokensPerUser]);
    }
  } 

cron.schedule('* * * * *', async () => {
  
  const numUsers = await countUsers();
  // Calculate number of tokens to refund (80% of tokens)
  const tokensToRefund = 0.8 * numUsers * 100;
  // Store number of tokens to refund
  localStorage.setItem('tokensToRefund', tokensToRefund);
});



cron.schedule('*/2 * * * *', async () => {
  // Get number of tokens to refund from local storage
  const tokensToRefund = localStorage.getItem('tokensToRefund');
  // Get number of users
  const numUsers = await countUsers();
  refundTokens(tokensToRefund, numUsers);
});
```

The first block seems to be running correctly every minute but the second one never does run. I see it because the console.log i have inside the refundTokens() function are not given. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: There is no `localStorage` in node.js

Comment: @Marc what can I use instead of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that there's no `localStorage` in NodeJS, as Marc said in comments. Try saving your tokens in some tmp file using Node's.

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

```
const numUsers = await countUsers();
// Calculate number of tokens to refund (80% of tokens)
const tokensToRefund = 0.8 * numUsers * 100;
// Store number of tokens to refund
await fs.writeFile('tmp', tokensToRefund);
```

```
// Get number of tokens to refund from local storage
const tokensFromFile = await fs.readFile('tmp');
const tokensToRefund = parseInt(tokensFromFile);
// Get number of users
const numUsers = await countUsers();
refundTokens(tokensToRefund, numUsers);
```

I would also write some separate helper function for this and add an Error handling, because both write and read functions could throw an error

P.S.: I would also recommend not to schedule your cronjobs in code for those small tasks, but to set them directly in console or in your backend panel. It would save you a huge amount of time and it will be much easier to configure them later. For your case, I consider it will be better. Just write your code as normal and add a cronjob to execute your js whenever you want

Comment: someone else told me that it would be better to use an event trigger straight into postgresql is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and it would be even a better solution. I'd recommend you this article: [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/introduction-postgresql-trigger/)